# Why do we need Laplace Transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

If Fourier transforms can depict all types of signals, why do need Laplace transforms?

Can't Fourier transform handle exponential signals (or damped oscillations)?

Comment: Not every signal has its fourier transform. There are two conditions a signal must satisfy in order to have reversible fourier transormation.

Comment: For the existence of Fourier transform, I think just the function should be absolutely integrable.

Comment: Actually, either a signal or it's square must be absolutely integrable. See Dirichlet statements about this topic.

Comment: Doesn't those conditions apply to Laplace transforms as well?

Comment: The Laplace transform simply avoids the use of Dirac distributions. Otherwise there isn't much difference. For example, initial conditions in differential equations are more easily taken care of with the Laplace transform.

Comment: Dealing with time signals for $t > 0$ of exponential order is handled nicely by the Laplace transform. Plus there is the advantage of being able to invoke Complex Analysis when inverting the transform. Poles of the transform correspond to resonances of the system, and the positions of these poles tells you about frequency and stability. Complex function theory plays a fundamental role in systems studied for $t > 0$. This type of analysis came first, from O. Heaviside, who basically started signal analysis.

Comment: I saw this video, [The Laplace Transform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGPtPkTft8g)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-laplace-transform-when-we-have-Fourier-transform
I hope this link helps. Abhishek Aich, Research Scholar (M.S.) at National Institute of Technology, nicely explains the need of laplace transform.